# How to clone UIElement in Silverlight

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

Can anybody tell me how to **clone UIElement in *SILVERLIGHT*** ?. I dug a lot in the google but I'm not able to find relevant solution, everywhere I'm just getting solution to clone UIElement in WPF, however same is not applicable in the Silverlight.

I need to add the a UIElement in the same grid's next rows on click of a + button eachtime.

Plz help..any answer will be appreciable

Thanks
GK

Answer (score 0):

There is no facility to do that.

In your scenario you can use an `ItemsControl` (directly or as a `ListBox`, for example) and provide your to-be-duplicated piece of UI as a datatemplate:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabelText}" />
            </Grid>
        <DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is the most typical way of doing it, but you will need to know about databinding to do it.

There is also the possibility of factoring out your to-be-duplicated piece of UI in a `UserControl` and add that programmatically multiple times.